# Access SharedPreferences that are edited in a PreferenceFragment under another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have one main activity with multiple Fragments. From the menu, the user can go to a new activity which contains the PreferenceFragment:

Preference Activity and Fragment:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.options_screen);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows the preferences for the first header.
     */
    public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_options);
        }
    }
}
```

Preferences xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_cat_display">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_key_display_units"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_units"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_units"
            android:entries="@array/entries_list_units"
            android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_units"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_dialog_title_list_units"
            android:defaultValue="0"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings_content"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.cs.biodyapp.usl.activity.SettingsActivity$Prefs1Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Once the option has been initialized, I try to access to this preference from the original Activity but I always get an empty Map in the SharedPreferences object.

I tried many ways that supposely let you access preferences form a different activity or directly from the file but no chance:

```
//SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("pref_options", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int units = sharedPref.getInt("pref_key_display_units", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Is the correct line to use ( getting the application context and not the base context ).

I also detected a problem in using `ListPreference` with integer arrays in a `PreferenceFragment`. Finally I had to use string arrays and `sharedPrefs.getString()` to then cast it to an integer.